# No "a" article - with (a) reason

Tags: articles

I was reading an article about the difference of empathy and sympathy. But it started with a sentence, "The terms empathy and sympathy are often confused, and with good reason." Why is that there's no "a" after "with"?

Answer (score 4):

*Reason* here is not countable.  It's similar to saying something like this:

> He's a good worker, with good skill.

We're not talking about *skill* in the sense of a specific skill, but just saying there's an abundance of a certain quality of skill, which isn't countable.

Similarly, in the example, we're not talking about *reason* in the sense of a specific reason, but just saying there's an abundance of a certain quality of reason, which isn't countable.  *Reason*  when used this way means *rational* or *done in a manner that makes sense*.

Comment: Do you have any tip to know the other words that can also be used this way?

Comment: If you can say "how much X" you can use the word this way.

Comment: I can replace X with any word.

Comment: Is it okay to say: how much illusion did we make?

Comment: Sounds a little clumsy but not terrible.  *How much of an illusion* sounds better.